# Stream groupingBy sub type

Tags: java, java-stream

I've 2 entites:

```
class Parent {
    Integer id;
    List<Child> children;
}

class Child {

    Integer id;
    Parent parent;
}
```

In my DB query I'm fetching a list of `Parents`.
Now I want to group this list by Child IDs, i.e.

```
Map<Integer, List<Parent>> myMap;
```

Using Java 8's grouping by how can I do this?

Right now I'm using `resultList.stream().collect(groupingBy(Parent::getChildren))`, but this creates `Map<Set<Child>, List<Parent>>`, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question without sample data. I recommend you post sample data and the expected output so that you can get correct answers.

Comment: Does every child has a reference to its own parent?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you may find [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) useful here:

```
Map<Integer, List<Parent>> childMap = 
    resultList.stream()
              .flatMap(Parent::getChildren)
              .collect(groupingBy(Child::getId, Collectors.mapping(Child::getParent,                                        
                                                    Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: A better way I think. But there is a catch, for every parent's every child has parent data available ? My initial thinking was not available

Comment: the existing code shouldn't compile, you would need an explicit `mapping` collector as a downstream to `groupingBy` for this.

Comment: @Naman Ah, understood. As shown in Eklavya's solution. Monkey see, monkey do, ha...

Answer (score 1):

Use `flatMap` to get the children. Then create map entry for child id and parent. Then grouping by child id the map entry list and collect the map entry groups value as list.

```
Map<Integer, List<Parent>> myMap = 
      resultList
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getChildren().stream()
                       .map(a -> new SimpleEntry<Integer,Parent>(a.getId(), e)))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                       Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                          Collectors.toList())));
```

Or more simplified using the constructor of Child

```
Map<Integer, List<Parent>> myMap = 
      resultList
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getChildren().stream()
                       .map(a -> new Child(a.getId(), e)))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Child::getId, Collectors.mapping(Child::getParent,
                                                          Collectors.toList())));
```

And if for every parent's every child has parent data available then @cs95 solution is better.

Comment: Looks a bit complicated. Better use loops?

Comment: @HarshalParekh Because the problem is complicated I think.

Comment: @HarshalParekh - I don't think your comment is required without you posting the solution using loops. One can clearly observe how delicately Eklavya has done it. If you can't encourage someone, don't discourage him/her at least.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash it is relevant. Eklavya can make a point that it’s more readable using loops. Just because using streams solves it, doesn’t mean it is not worth mentioning.

Comment: the latter [wouldn't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62270496/stream-groupingby-sub-type#comment110136137_62270633)